# Why does an error appear on compiling time v0.3.34 when installing wasm-pack?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, wasm-pack

Running

```
cargo install wasm-pack
```

I get many green lines of "Compiling" and then the following

```
   Compiling time v0.3.34
error[E0602]: unknown lint: `invalid_reference_casting`
  |
  = note: requested on the command line with `-D invalid_reference_casting`

error[E0602]: unknown lint: `invalid_nan_comparisons`
  |
  = note: requested on the command line with `-D invalid_nan_comparisons`

error[E0602]: unknown lint: `invalid_from_utf8`
  |
  = note: requested on the command line with `-D invalid_from_utf8`

error[E0602]: unknown lint: `hidden_glob_reexports`
  |
  = note: requested on the command line with `-D hidden_glob_reexports`

   Compiling object v0.32.2
   Compiling pbkdf2 v0.11.0
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0602`.
error: could not compile `time` (lib) due to 4 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

What's happening and how do I fix it?

I'm trying out Rust so I don't know what to do with this.
I'm on Ubuntu and my `cargo --version` is `cargo 1.75.0`

Comment: Does it require a "nightly" build of Rust that has those flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lints are newly-introduced:

- `invalid_reference_casting`: 1.72 or later
- `invalid_nan_comparisons`: 1.72 or later
- `invalid_from_utf8`: 1.72 or later

Some of crates have "MSRV", which defines most lowest version that the crate maintainer make effort to be compiled.
[`time`'s "MSRV"](https://github.com/time-rs/time#minimum-rust-version-policy) is latest stable and two prior version from it, so its MSRV is `1.74` as of writing (current latest stable release is `1.76.0`).

I assume your toolchain is outdated.Try `rustup toolchain list` and update them by `rustup update`.

Comment: installing rust from curl rustup (instead of apt) fixed it, thanks. I'm surprised it wouldn't tell me what's wrong